"no such column: poll_poll.option_five" error message and can't make migrate
I'm making a poll app via Django and Python.
There were 1question and 4 options to choose. It worked well.
Now, I'm trying to increase the number of options from 4 to 6.
After adjusting options, I made migrations and when do the migrate below error message came out.
"no such column: poll_poll.option_five"
I input these codes in root directory.
"py manage.py makemigrations"
"py manage.py migrate"
What should I do for that?

I found a solution!  First, I needed to delete "db.sqlite3" and every files under migrations folder except "init.py" file and "pycache" folder. After that I applied the command "py manage.py makemigrations" and "py manage.py migrate"   I made it!
